# How to ensure UITableView header cell subview with repeating animation continues animating after a reloadData, user scroll, etc?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a ViewController with a header cell that is working well, except that one view in the header cell has a repeating animation that should continue animating endlessly when particular conditions are set in the view controller.  I can start the animation sometimes successfully in viewDidLoad and restart it in my handler for the .appDidBecomeActive notification.  However when the user scrolls or pulls to refresh the tableview data, the animation stops.  I did override the scrollViewDidEndDragging & scrollViewDidEndDecelerating methods to restart it, but its not actually reliably restarting the animation.  Clues?

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse, .repeat, .beginFromCurrentState],
                       animations: { self.headerCellAnimatedSubview?.alpha = 1.0 },
                       completion: { _ in  self.headerCellAnimatedSubview?.alpha = 0.0 }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

After some help I found that adding the animation call to the UITableViewHeaderCell class's override of didMoveToWindow the animation will restart after scroll.  However as expected I also had to respond to the appDidBecomeActive notification to restart the animation when the app returns fro background.